# Redis Server after loading from dump.rdb deleting all keys

Tags: redis, ubuntu-14.04, redis-server

I have my redis server in my local and when i copy those contents with dump.rdb bgsave and put it in my other machine .Every thing works fine but after some inactivity my keys keep getting deleted and I'm ending up with 433KB of dump file and my dump file being replaced.What am i doing wrong?I have 3.0.3 in local and 2.8.4 in my other machine.I am following steps from this [link][1]. I couldn't able to figure out this issue.I checked the server logs and there's no error there just only those bgsaves for every 900,300 seconds.Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly this is probably because

- Your Redis instance is open to a public network and isn't using password authentication - crackers can do anything for deleting your keys to compromising the server.
- All your keys are set to expire
- You are using an eviction policy such as `all-keys`, your `maxmemory` is set and you've reached it.
- You have a rogue piece of code that deletes them.

Comment: My keys are not set to expire and all keys are not deleting except those which are created on server are still in that only those i uploaded through dump file is keep getting deleted.

Comment: If i do have a rogue piece of code that deletes them i should face in my local as well right.maxmemory is out of issue here.